# How to know the version of headless chrome browser in protractor?

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, google-chrome-headless

I am using chrome headless browser with protractor to test the application following this [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md) I had turned out my chrome to be headless.

It states that :

> As of Chrome 58 you also need to set --disable-gpu, though this may
>   change in future versions.

**1** How can I know my headless chrome version so that I can be sure to use this flag.

**2** If I dont use this flag it displays Failed to launch GPU and using this does not displays the above.

**3** How can I update my headless browser?

Answer (score 0):

**1** How can I know my headless chrome version so that I can be sure to use this flag.

```
var script = 'return navigator.userAgent.match(/(Chrome.*?)\s/)[1];';
browser.executeScript(script).then(function(version){
   console.log(version);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Always use this flag for running chrome in headless mode;
2) see point #1
3) Headless is just a mode of browser. So your statement does not have sense.